# Derive composite function w.r.t. inner function and variables of inner function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I need to do some calculation using a general function `F[ξ]` where `ξ` is defined as

```
ξ[r_, v_] =  r/Sqrt[r^2 + a^2] Exp[i (Sqrt[2] v)/Ry]
```

However, I need to use both the derivative of `F[ξ]` w.r.t `ξ` and w.r.t. `v` or `r`. I could of course easily do this using the chain rule but sadly the derivatives are hidden in function I have to use from a Mathematica package. Is there any way to get Mathematica to understand that `F[ξ[r_, v_]]` is a composite function while still being able to take the derivative w.r.t. `ξ`?

Comment: What is `F`? You might be able to solve this problem by using `ReplaceAll` to replace all instances of `ξ` with the value of your expression here, but it’s not clear enough to  answer without an example definition of `F`.

Comment: hmm, I'm a little confused. does `F` take in a number or a function itself? and if `\[Xi]` has a specific value (as a function), how are you taking the derivative with respect to it? are you simply trying to talk about the derivative of `F` "by itself" as one would in e.g. a chain rule?

Comment: F is just some holomorphic function (preferably i want Mathematica to treat it as a unknown function And just write F' where a derivative w.r.t. xi is needed) of xi but this can also expressed as a function of v and r by using the explicit form of xi.